# Passing data back between View Controllers embed in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

I have view controller embed in navigation controller with one property (nonatomic strong NSMutableArray *myData), when I am pushing second view I am also passing my array data to this view using this method:

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {  
      if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"secondView"]) {
          SecondViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
          svc.myDataInSecondView = self.myData;
     }
```

My question is: Why if I change any values in my myDataInSecondView array and than I will come back to first view my values in myData array are changed as well? I always thought that I have to use custom protocols and delegates to pass any data back to the previous view.

Comment: If you're passing a pointer to data to another controller and that changes the data then it changes for both.

Comment: yes in this case, but it depends of how is that property declared

Comment: Does it make a difference if I will declare property from first view as weak instead of strong? If it will be weak property and I will move to second view will myData object be deallocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it is a very common way of sharing data between view controllers. The second view controller has a property that can be set by the first view controller. The property is a pointer, the same as in the first view controller. Both point at the same place in memory, so either view controller can change that same data.

If you don't want the second view controller to alter the data, set the property as `copy`.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyData *myData;
```